# Retrieve repeated month data in separate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

MySql query is like this

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(access_date) as date,
  DATE_FORMAT( access_date,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) as month_date, 
  COUNT( log_id ) as total_count
    FROM user_activity_log
    WHERE dam_id = (
        SELECT dam_id 
            FROM dam_content_details
            WHERE content_type= 'userLogin'
        ) 
    AND CAST(access_date as DATE) BETWEEN '2012-09-01'
        AND '2014-01-01'
    GROUP BY MONTH( access_date )
    ORDER BY access_date ASC
```

1. The problem i faced is the data of November & December in 2012 year is adding with November & December of 2013 year & showing in a one row. But i want to be separate rows for this.
2. The second one is its only showing the first 12 months not up to 2014 January.

My sample output is like this

```
date        month_date  total_count
---------  ------------ -----------
September   15/09/2012  7
October     05/10/2012  34
November    05/11/2012  21
December    07/12/2012  49
January     01/01/2013  45
February    02/02/2013  107
March       01/03/2013  158
April       01/04/2013  100
May         01/05/2013  393
June        01/06/2013  272
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Monthname(access_date)               AS DATE, 
       Date_format(access_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS month_date, 
       Count(log_id)                        AS total_count 
FROM   user_activity_log 
WHERE  dam_id = (SELECT dam_id 
                 FROM   dam_content_details 
                 WHERE  content_type = 'userLogin') 
       AND Cast(access_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
GROUP  BY Year(access_date), 
          Month(access_date) 
ORDER  BY access_date ASC
```

**OR**

Query WITH `JOIN`

```
SELECT Monthname(ual.access_date)               AS DATE, 
       Date_format(ual.access_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS month_date, 
       Count(DISTINCT ual.log_id)               AS total_count 
FROM   user_activity_log ual 
       INNER JOIN dam_content_details dcd 
               ON ual.dam_id = dcd.dam_id 
                  AND dcd.content_type = 'userLogin' 
WHERE  ual.access_date BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2014-01-01' 
GROUP  BY Year(ual.access_date), 
          Month(ual.access_date) 
ORDER  BY ual.access_date ASC
```